# How to copy any file to isolatedstorage in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding files to WP7 isolated storage from Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690815/adding-files-to-wp7-isolated-storage-from-visual-studio)

I want save database file to isolated storage. My database already exists. I want to deploy database to isolated storage

How to do that?

**EDIT**

Maybe in the future, Visual Studio->Solution Explorer-> Build Action contains "Deploy to Isolated storage" option.
Therefore after installing app on the mobile, chosen files deployed to "Isolated storage". This is only my idea. not real.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of another question, see my answer for details on the Mango SDK utility that can deploy files to the isolated storage of a device or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes we do have those tools. One of those is called [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and is bundled with the SDK. You can find more details on using it [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-isolatedstorage-explorer). The next question would be what is the format of the database and how you're going to read it, but that's a separate topic.

Answer (score -1):

We don't have tools for upload data to isolate storage directly now. But I think you can use next workaround. Make external WCF or web service (publish you database file like as stream). After that connect you WP7 application to this service and save stream to isolate storage.